# Getting data from Cassandra tables to MongoDB/RDBMS in realtime

Tags: python, cassandra, mongodb-query, pipeline, rdbms

I have an application which is using Cassandra as a database.I need to create some kind of reports from the Cassanbdra DB data, but data is not modelled as per report queries. So one report may have data scattered in multiple tables. As Cassandra doesn't allow joins like RDBMS, this is not simple to do.So I am thinking of a solution to get the required tables data in some other DB (RDBMS or Mongo) in real time and then genereate the report from there. So do we have any standard way to get the data from Cassandra to other DBs (Mongo or RDBMS) in realtime i.e. whenever an insert/update/delete happens in Cassandra same has to eb updated in destination DB. Any example programe or code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using spark + spark cassandra connector combination to do this task. With Spark you can do joins in memory and write the data back to Cassandra or any text file.

Comment: But my tables sizes are huge (more than 5 million records). How will get them in memory for doing joins.

Comment: You need to write logic /code to bring that much into memory which can be accommodated.  Seen reports generated with over 550 million records. It can be handled though you  will need the spark understanding.